# Unexplained value for __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ using F# VS2013 on Win8 virtual machine

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

The fsharp spec, defines `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` as: "A literal verbatim string that specifies the name of the directory that contains the 
current file..."

However, when I query it in fsi, I get a different directory.

Specifically, I am expecting:
z:\desktop\dropbox\dev\xenomorph

whereas I am actually getting:
c:\Users\Vij\AppData\Local\Temp

I am using visual studio 13 on a windows 8 virtual machine created in Parallels 9 on Mac OS 10.9.

Any ideas what's happening here? More importantly, how could I set the value to the one that I expect. (My current situation means that any `#r` directives involving `"../"` have to be manually hard-coded.)

thanks
Vijesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas what's happening here?

If you manually enter in the VS FSI window

```
printfn __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__;;
```

you will get something like

```
C:\...
```

If you enter in an fsx file and then send to FSI

```
printfn __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__;;
```

you will get the directory where the fsx file is located like

```
E:\Projects...
```

Note: I did these examples using VS 2010 on Windows 7.

See my `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` [notes](https://github.com/jack-pappas/NHol/blob/master/NHol/Logging.fs#L93)

> How could I set the value to the one that I expect?

There has been a change between VS 2010 and VS 2012 when using relative directories, but if it works for VS 2010 it works for VS2012 but not the other way around.

In our project we used an [initialization.fsx](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/Examples/initialization.fsx) file which correctly uses #I and #r. e.g.

```
#I @".\..\FSharpx.Books.AutomatedReasoning\bin\Debug"
#r @"FSharpx.Books.AutomatedReasoning.dll"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - it solved my problem. Thank you also for the link to the notes on github - they've helped me understand something I wasn't previously aware of.